# Oracle sql to case conversion for every adjacent characters in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

With a condition like no two adjacent characters ( from a to z) should be in same case;
I need to change `helloworld` to `HeLlOwOrLd` , and used a query like :

```
SELECT listagg(jumping_char,'') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rn) jumped_word
FROM
     (SELECT rn,
          CASE
               WHEN mod(rn, 2) = 1
               THEN upper(split_word)
               ELSE lower(split_word)
          END jumping_char
     FROM
          (SELECT regexp_substr('helloworld','.',LEVEL)split_word,
               ROWNUM rn
          FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('helloworld')
          )
     );
```

Now I got a string like `hello2world` should becomes `HeLlO2wOrLd`.
Any simple ,different queries are appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to "skip" over non-characters in the input. You can achieve that by using regexp_count() with an offset of rn (instead of simply using rn) in your old solution:

```
SELECT listagg(jumping_char,'') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rn) jumped_word
FROM
     (SELECT rn,
          CASE
               when mod (regexp_count('hello2world', '[a-zA-Z]', rn), 2) = 1
               THEN upper(split_word)
               ELSE lower(split_word)
          END jumping_char
     FROM
          (SELECT regexp_substr('hello2world','.',LEVEL)split_word,
               ROWNUM rn
          FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('hello2world')
          )
     );
```

UPDATE:

Here's an alternative solution using the MODEL clause, just for completeness' sake:

```
with t as 
  (select 'hello2world' txt from dual)
select listagg(case 
                 when mod(v2.char_cnt, 2) = 1 
                 then upper(v2.txt) 
                 else lower(v2.txt) 
               end, 
               '') within group(order by v2.rn)
from (
  select 
    v1.txt, 
    rownum as rn, 
    sum(case 
          when regexp_like(txt, '[a-zA-Z]') 
          then 1 
          else 0 
        end) over (partition by 1 order by rownum) as char_cnt
  from (
    SELECT TXT   
    FROM T
    MODEL
      RETURN UPDATED ROWS
      PARTITION BY(ROWNUM RN)
      DIMENSION BY (0 POSITION)
      MEASURES     (TXT ,length(txt) NB_MOT)
      RULES 
        (TXT[FOR POSITION FROM  1 TO NB_MOT[0] INCREMENT 1] = 
          substr(txt[0], CV(POSITION), 1)  )
   ) v1      
) v2
```

Comment: Nice and thanks for the right way, Is there any other shortcuts to achieve this?

Comment: I guess you could also use the MODEL clause - I'll try to come up with an alternative using it.

Comment: Let Oracle learn the both above to create a new char conversion function:)

Comment: And I'l take little time to learn the new one. :). Thanks and appreciate for your worthy try.